# How to round down a number to nearest hundred in VBA?

Tags: vba

I need to round down a number to nearest hundred like these:
For example:
54678 become 54600
54611 become 54600
54699 become 54600
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: `x = int(num / 100) * 100`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rounddown.php) you can find the code basics for the `RoundDown` command which allows you to round numbers up to a certain number of digits.

What you need to do is basically for example divide your number by 100, then round them and again multiply by 100. It's an easy workaround... but should work!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 54699 to become 54700, but just want it to be 54600, there is an easy solution.
If the number is stored as an integer (no decimal point), just divide it by 100, then multiply it by 100 again

If it is not stored as an integer, you will need to divide it by 100, cast it to an integer and then multiply it by 100